# Determine if the three matrices span the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Thus far I've seen vectors and polynomials but this the first and only exercise I find that introduces matrices.

The question is as follows:

> Determine whether the three matrices
>
> $\begin{pmatrix}
>     1 &  1 \\
>     1 & 0\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
>     -1 &  0 \\
>     0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}
>      0 &  1 \\
>     1 & 2\\ \end{pmatrix}$
>
> span the vector space of all 2x2 symmetric matrices.

I am stuck at this stage because previously I would find the matrix of the vectors or polynomials and work on that, but this time it's 3 matrices, what are the steps that I should follow to always get it right?

Comment: Someone voted to close this as "lacking context". I don't think that is appropriate -- the OP explains enough of how they're stuck that it is possible to write an answer that addresses their specific lack of understanding. It is not just asking for a solution that can be handed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Since we are dealing with symmetric matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
    a &  b \\
    b & c\\ \end{pmatrix}$ the dimension of the space is 3 and we can consider the equivalent vectors $(a,b,c)$. Therefore to find the dimension of the subspace spanned by the three matrices let arrange each matrix as a vector row in a 3-by-3 matrix and perform the RREF.

Comment: We really haven't learned yet about dimensions, just span for now. To make sure I understood correctly, the three vectors become (1,1,0) , (-1, 0, 1) and (0,1,2). And from these three I could create the 3x3 matrix and then solve normally?

Comment: Yes exactly! from here you can use RREF

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

The vector space of all s
$2\times 2$ symmetric matrices has dimension $3$. To show three symmetric matrices span this vector space, you can make do with proving they're linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

When you're viewing a set of matrices as a *vector space*, you're ignoring the matrix multiplication, so the rectangular arrangement of the elements of each matrix is irrelevant. Eseentiall you can treat them as belonging in $\mathbb R^{nm}$. So the question is equivalent to asking whether $$\{(1,1,1,0),(-1,0,0,1),(0,1,1,2)\}$$ spans the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ that corresponds to the symmetric matrices, which is $\{(a,b,b,c)\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: Then that would mean I would be working with an nxm matrix to find the solution? $$\begin{pmatrix}
     1 &  -1  &  0\\
    1 & 0 &   1\\
    1 &  0 &  1\\
     0 &  1 &  2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I proceed normally after here?

Comment: @KodeCh: Yes, if that is the way around you would normally compute the span of three length-4 vectors. My instinct would be to look at the tanspose of your matrix, and then do ordinary Gaussuan elimination where the _row operations_ do not change the row space (aka the span), but the other way around would also work, and I believe there are textbooks that teach it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Take an arbitrary symmetric matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{pmatrix}$$
and compute $a, b, c$ such that
\begin{align*}\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ y & z \end{pmatrix} &= a\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} a - b & a + c \\ a + c & b + 2c \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Equating entries, this produces the system of linear equations,
\begin{align*}
a - b &= x \\
a + c &= y \\
b + 2c &= z,
\end{align*}
which can be solved using whichever methods you like. Either way, we get
\begin{align*}
a &= -x + 2y - z \\
b &= -2x + 2y - z \\
c &= x - y + z.
\end{align*}
In particular, at least one solution exists regardless of the value of $x, y, z$. That is, the arbitrary symmetric matrix is spanned by the the three matrices.